# Merge and fill different length data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, factors, tibble, data-transform

I'm using R and need merge data with different lenghts

Following this dataset

```
> means2012
 # A tibble: 232 x 2
   exporter    eci
   <fct>     <dbl>
 1 ABW       0.235
 2 AFG      -0.850
 3 AGO      -1.40 
 4 AIA       1.34 
 5 ALB      -0.480
 6 AND       1.22 
 7 ANS       0.662
 8 ARE       0.289
 9 ARG       0.176
 10 ARM       0.490
 # ... with 222 more rows

> means2013
 # A tibble: 234 x 2
    exporter     eci
    <fct>      <dbl>
  1 ABW       0.534 
  2 AFG      -0.834 
  3 AGO      -1.26  
  4 AIA       1.47  
  5 ALB      -0.498 
  6 AND       1.13  
  7 ANS       0.616 
  8 ARE       0.267 
  9 ARG       0.127 
 10 ARM       0.0616
 # ... with 224 more rows


> str(means2012)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   232 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ exporter: Factor w/ 242 levels "ABW","AFG","AGO",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 ...
 $ eci     : num  0.235 -0.85 -1.404 1.337 -0.48 ...
> str(means2013)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   234 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ exporter: Factor w/ 242 levels "ABW","AFG","AGO",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 ...
 $ eci     : num  0.534 -0.834 -1.263 1.471 -0.498 ...
```

Note that 2 tibble has different lenghts. "Exporter" are countries.

**Is there any way to merge both tibble, looking to the factors (Exporter) and fill the missing it with "na"?**

It doesn't matter if is a tibble, dataframe, or other kind.

like this:

```
tibble 1
a 5
b 10
c 15
d 25

tibble 2
a 7
c 23
d 20

merged one:
a 5  7 
b 10 na
c 15 23
d 25 20
```

Comment: `left_join` will help.

Comment: MKR, got same error using the other dplyr solution: **Error: `by` must be a (named) character vector, list, or NULL for natural joins (not recommended in production code), not list**

Comment: You should  provide `by = exporter`. May be you should use `full_join` if you want to including missing values from both tibbles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `merge` with parameter `all` set to `TRUE`:

```
tibble1 <- read.table(text="
x y
a 5
b 10
c 15
d 25",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

tibble2 <- read.table(text="
x z
a 7
c 23
d 20",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


merge(tibble1,tibble2,all=TRUE)

  x  y  z
1 a  5  7
2 b 10 NA
3 c 15 23
4 d 25 20
```

Or `dplyr::full_join(tibble1,tibble2)` for the same effect

Comment: First option returned: **Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
  'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical**. And the second one returned **"Error: `by` must be a (named) character vector, list, or NULL for natural joins (not recommended in production code), not list"**

Comment: Using the data from my answer ?

Comment: No, using my data.

Comment: If a solution works on your reproducible example but not on your real data, you should update your reproducible example to reflect the issue.

Comment: Found the error. Merge worked perfect. 
The simple error here was trying to merge more than 2 tibble at same time. 
Doing it over a loop, 2 by 2 it worked fine. 

Thanks Moody

Comment: you're welcome, look up `Reduce` if you want to merge several tables in one operation

Comment: Ok. I will do =)

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the colums to join them, and get `NA` where the other value is missing.

```
library(tidyverse)

means2012 %>% 
  rename(eci2012 = eci) %>% 
  full_join(means2013 %>% 
              rename(eci2013 = eci))
```

But a tidier approach would be to add a `year` column, keep the column `eci` as is and just bind the rows together.

```
means2012 %>% 
  mutate(year = 2012) %>% 
  bind_rows(means2013 %>% 
              mutate(year = 2013))
```